# deleting a post in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

hi ive read some of similar posts but couldn't find same problem.
i wrote a code to delete post and when i press delete it shows 404 error but when back to home post is still there
views:

```
def delete_music_view(request,music_id):
    # view for deleting music
    my_object = add_music.objects.get(id=music_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_object.delete()
        return redirect('pages:home')   
    context = {'my_object':my_object}

    return render(request,'pages/delete_music.html',context)
```

url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('add_music/',views.add_music_view,name='add_music'),
    path('musics/<int:music_id>',views.musics_view,name='music_page'),
    path('musics/<int:music_id>/delete',views.delete_music_view,name='delete_music'),
]
```

template:

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" name="delete" value="yes"><a href="../../">cancel</a></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

can u pls tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `delete_music_view` method is going to handle the `POST` request there's no need to use the form attribute `action`. You have:

```
<form action="." method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" name="delete" value="yes"><a href="../../">cancel</a></p>
</form>
```

Remove the `action` from your form and have this instead:

```
<form method='POST'>  # Removing the action attribute
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" name="delete" value="yes"><a href="../../">cancel</a></p>
</form>
```

That should work.

Also, note that `<a href="../../">cancel</a>` will show you another `404 error` if you don't set a recognizable `url` for `django` to handle.

I hope this answer helps.